# Automatic Mastering Software For Linux

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, music, audio-recording

is there an automatic mastering software for **Linux** (preferably Ubuntu) where a few presets could be selected and then the wav file would become the master, whic you can use to upload to your favorite music distribution platform like sone Windows program listed below do?

- T-RackS 5 - **IK Multimedia**
- AAMS Auto Audio Mastering System
- iZotope **Ozone 9**

Please reply with link or full name of the software in question, once found.

Thank you

Comment: Plz give more details, couldn't understand what exactly is your problem with ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I see that you have this tagged *windows-subsystem-for-linux*, which is a feature of Microsoft Windows that allows Linux distributions and applications to run natively under Windows.  However, your question does not seem to be about that at all.  I've submitted an edit to the question to remove that tag, since we find that new users often use it without realizing what it is.  If you really do mean to be asking about Windows Subsystem for Linux, please do edit your question to clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: I was going to elaborate more on the Windows based system but didn't, I wanted to know ifthere is a way to use the windows oriented plugin on Linux and the contributor below answered that question. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 3):

I would say your best bet here is to install [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org).

This distribution has the necessary tools for audio production and mastering. Also, quote from the [audio section](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/):

> Carla ... Has a plugin bridge that utilizes WINE to use plugins compiled for Windows devices (experimental, not installed by default).

So maybe you can get your favorite Windows mastering plugins to work with this.

Also, there is the Traktion [Master Mix plugin](https://www.tracktion.com/products/master-mix) in Linux VST format.